# Swift 3 and NumberFormatter (.currency) == ¤?

Tags: ios, locale, swift3, ios10, nsnumberformatter

**Xcode** 8.0 (8A218a) GM
**Target**: iOS 10 (Swift 3)

Consider the following code:

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 22.4)

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current

let result = numberFormatter.string(from: number)
print(result!)
```

The result is:

```
¤22.40
```

(I have no idea what `¤` means.)

But if I initialize the locale such as:

```
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
```

The result will be:

```
$22.40
```

... which is what I'd expect in the first place.

Notice that this works in a Playground tho:

[image]

The problem seems to happen only on devices/simulators via Xcode launching.
(I tested on two different macOS -- at my workplace and at home.)

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: What's your current locale?

Comment: What does `Locale.current` give you?

Comment: (lldb) po Locale.current
▿ en (current)
  - identifier : "en"
  - kind : "current"

Comment: That appears to be the issue. Your "current" locale only has a language, not a country. Are you testing this on a real device or the simulator? Either way, go to the Language & Region page in the Settings app and make sure a Region is selected in addition to a language.

Comment: Another option is to not set the `locale` property of the formatter. It will default to your current locale so there is never any reason to set it to the current locale.

Comment: I tested on a real device and on a simulator. Both produce the same result. The Region is set in Language & Region. I also tried to *not* set the `locale` property in code, but the result is the same. This looks like a bug :/. I'm going to open a Radar. Thanks for the tips anyway.

Comment: I can confirm that this WORKS in a Playground, but not via Xcode on a simulator / device. I updated my question with this info.

Comment: The ¤ character is the Unicode "CURRENCY SIGN" character. It's the character that will be used to display the currency if the locale doesn't have any information which currency to use, or how to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: recreate the project. :\

The project was started off in Xcode 7 + Swift 2 and then "migrated" to Xcode 8 + Swift 3 (manually). Something must have gone wrong. I don't know what (and I don't want to know).

This wasn't a huge project, so I spent like 40 minutes moving files around. If that was a big project I would be f....d by now.

Xcode pls.

Answer (score 15):

I have same problems and I solve it by below code. Hope it is useful

```
func formatCurrency(value: Double) -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: Locale.current.identifier)
    let result = formatter.string(from: value as NSNumber)
    return result!
}
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to set the maximum fraction digits manually, as they vary from 0 to 3. They number of digits should be set based on the locale.

Answer (score 5):

This was happening to me in the Simulator, turns out it was an error in my scheme setup.  Checkout the following steps:

1. Click on Set Active Scheme (click directly to the left of the simulator type i.e. iPhone 7 Plus etc.)
2. Click **Edit Scheme...**
3. Click into the **Run** settings on the left
4. Set **Application Region** to desired region
5. Set **Application Language** to desired language
6. Try running your application again, you should no longer have it displaying the "¤" symbol and instead it should reflect the correct currency symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I think your device language set to be chinese
that is why ¤ symbol shown as currency symbol

Comment: That's not the case. The device is/was set to en-US.