# Spacing between currency symbol and value: iOS swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, number-formatting

I am having an app with IAP. I need to show the prices with values based on location. I have made till this. Now I am able to display the prices based on location.

However, I need some spacing between currency symbol and the value.
i.e, I need $ 9.99 (currently it shows $9.99).

FYI: I am getting the price from itunes (used a variable to get the price got from itunes and displaying it in a textview).

I have followed this without success: [NSNumberFormatter paddingPosition doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761272/nsnumberformatter-paddingposition-doesnt-work)

I have also referred this, but it does not work as well: 
[Swift 3 and NumberFormatter (.currency) == ¤?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458003/swift-3-and-numberformatter-currency-%C2%A4)

Any suggestions?

I am doing this:

```
var index: Int = 0 {
    didSet {

        var monthlyValue = String()

        if prefs.value(forKey: "monthly") != nil {

            monthlyValue = prefs.value(forKey: "monthly") as! String


        }

        let subcharges : Array<String>   = ["Free but limited just to get started","or \(monthlyValue) Billed Monthly",""]

        let yearlypermonth = Int()

        var mycurrency1 = String()

        if prefs.value(forKey: "yearly") != nil {

            let yearlyvalue = prefs.value(forKey: "yearly") as! String

            print("wallet view yearlyvalue: \(yearlyvalue)")

            let firstProduct  = StoreManager.shared.productsFromStore[0]

            if let mycurrency = firstProduct.priceLocale.currencySymbol {

                print("mycurrency: \(mycurrency)")

                mycurrency1 = mycurrency
                prefs.set(mycurrency, forKey: "mycurrency")

            }

            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .currency
//                formatter.paddingPosition = .afterPrefix
//
//                //formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
//                formatter.paddingCharacter = " "
//                formatter.formatWidth = 7


            let number1 = formatter.number(from: yearlyvalue)

            print("wallet view number1: \(number1)")

            let secondProd = StoreManager.shared.productsFromStore[1]

            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
//                numberFormatter.paddingPosition = .afterPrefix
//                numberFormatter.paddingCharacter = " "
//                numberFormatter.formatWidth = 7
            // Get its price from iTunes Connect
            numberFormatter.locale = secondProd.priceLocale
            let price2Str = numberFormatter.string(from: secondProd.price)

            let currencynumbers2 =  secondProd.price.doubleValue / 12

            monthonValueforaYear = String(format: "%.2f", currencynumbers2)

            print("walletview VC monthonValueforaYear: \(monthonValueforaYear)")

            //prefs.set(price2Str, forKey: "yearly")
            prefs.set(monthonValueforaYear, forKey: "monthonValueforaYear")

        }
        var charges : Array<String> = ["\(mycurrency1) 0/m","\(mycurrency1 + monthonValueforaYear)/m","Coming Soon"]

        print("wallet view charges: \(charges)")

        self.Headingtitle.text    = Headingarray[index]
        self.planchargelabel.text  = charges[index]
        self.subchargelabel.text = subcharges[index]
```

**Interestingly, for subchargelabel value, I get a little spacing**

**The commented section was uncommented while I tried running the app. Just so you know it**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Typographers prefer a Thin Space over a regular space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to format your required string as below.

```
let priceWithSpace: String? = firstProduct.priceLocale.currencySymbol + " " +   product.price
```

Answer (score 1):

Just putting symbol, space, and amount is not a good idea. It's sequence may differ by locale or currency. Following method will give you an answer.

```
func customFormattedAmountString(amount: Int) -> String? {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = Locale.current

    if let amountString = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: amount)) {
        // check if it has default space like EUR
        let hasSpace = amountString.rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespaces) != nil

        if let indexOfSymbol = amountString.characters.index(of: Character(formatter.currencySymbol)) {
            if amountString.startIndex == indexOfSymbol {
                formatter.paddingPosition = .afterPrefix
            } else {
                formatter.paddingPosition = .beforeSuffix
            }
        }
        if !hasSpace {
            formatter.formatWidth = amountString.characters.count + 1
            formatter.paddingCharacter = " "
        }
    } else {
        print("Error while making amount string from given amount: \(amount)")
        return nil
    }

    if let finalAmountString = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: amount)) {
        return finalAmountString
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Use it as below,

```
if let formattedAmount = customFormattedAmountString(amount: 5000000) {
    print(formattedAmount)
}
```

That will print out dollar,

```
$ 5,000,000.00
```

and Euro,

```
5.000.000,00 €
```

As you wanted to have space between currency symbol and amount. If you just append string like first answer, you'll get "€ 5.000.000,00", not a desired one - "5.000.000,00 €".

Comment: Hi @dragoncherry, BRL (R$) currency is getting crash `Fatal error: Can't form a Character from a String containing more than one extended grapheme cluster`. Thanks for your code!

Comment: To avoid the crash for multi-character symbols, e.g. R$: (Swift 5.1) Instead of using 'indexOfSymbol = amountString.index(of: Character(formatter.currencySymbol))', I used 'rangeOfSymbol = amountString.range(of: String(numberFormatter.currencySymbol)'. Then test with 'amountString.startIndex == rangeOfSymbol.lowerBound'

Answer (score 0):

set the formatWidth property and paddingPosition to afterPrefix

```
var formatCurrency:  String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.paddingPosition = .afterPrefix
    formatter.formatWidth = 6
    return formatter.string(for: self) ?? "N/A"   
}
```